# How to redirect all traffic through a proxy without a loop?

Tags: networking, iptables, configuration, proxy, lan

I want to redirect all traffic from my apps and programs (including those that do not support proxy or VPNs in their app configuration) to a local HTTP/SOCKS proxy server, which will then redirect the traffic to an online proxy server.

I created the following network topology:
[image: Network Topology]

However, I want to avoid creating a loop, where the local proxy server redirects traffic to the redirector, which then redirects it back to the local proxy server. Network Topology to Avoid:
[image: Network Topology to Avoid]

Comment: "those that do not support proxies" this class of software shouldn't exist. It probably doesn't – most HTTP clients just use a library for HTTP, and all libraries support proxies. If they actually don't, then you're out of luck - if you can't teach a program to use a proxy, you can also not teach it to ignore the glaring certificate errors you get when trying to tunnel HTTPS, which is hopefully almost all HTTP external traffic you have.

Comment: You did not specify, what do you have available. Which objects in your topology are standalone boxes, what can be used in these boxes,...

Comment: Your question appears like you already have done the setup with a loop. Can you provide it? Else the scope of the answer is not the same.

Comment: @A.B I've tried several ways, but they all failed to meet my needs. One of the things I tried was using tun2socks, using iptables. Either I'm using them incorrectly or they just don't meet my needs. I just want all traffic on my computer to enter a local proxy and exit without loops. The loops I mentioned earlier happen when I use tun2socks.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the correction and apologize for the misunderstanding. I meant applications that do not support proxy in their configuration. I have added it in the question to correct that.

Comment: @nobody In the topology I created, there is only one computer (excluding WAN). All that includes the application, local proxies, and redirectors.

Comment: So, you want to avoid some internal redirects, right? I guess no_proxy is not useful in you case? https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-configure-http-proxy-exceptions.html